# boolean and moving door

Tags: modifiers

I try to make the sliding doors partially disappear when opened, so that they do not pierce the wall.

However, when the boolean object is in contact with the doorframe it does not cover the area it is supposed to cover, it only erases the entire part of the object and appears and disappears when I move it (while normals are to outside it`s even worse mess).

When boolean object is not in contact with the doorframe it's looks okey, but that way part of the moving door is not affected by it.

The solution would be to make the boolean only affect a given Vertex Group, but I don't know how.

I could also cut the boolean object to make perfect contact with the doorframe, but I can't do that either - when I do it through the boolean modifier it doesn't work.

I also do not know how to make the effect set by the boolean permanently modify the mesh, in every tutorial it is done with the Apply button, but in my version there is nothing like that.

[image]

I tried apply scale, fixing normals etc.

Link to project file - https://mega.nz/file/baBn3KLS#ju69g5ALDidK2TBlMhfNf3jeo-Fm2zeP404P0Wa8X3M

Comment: it would have been nice, if you had you animation in the blend file....

Comment: do you want it like that? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moB1G.jpg

Comment: do you have to have the door as vertex group? because your life would be much easier, if you make it a seperate object....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go in Edit mode -> select your rdoor vertex group
2. Mesh -> Separate -> selection

[image]

3. delete your boolean modifier on door_cube.009
4. add a keyframe on frame 0 for your newly created door_cube.001 for location (from step 2)
5. go to frame 100
6. press <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>y</kbd> -> -5.   Then keyframe location.
7. move your boolean modifier like so:

[image]

8. enjoy animation:

https://youtu.be/J0703WlP3oQ

i will delete the video, if you don't want me to show that.